# what is difference between ASP.net .Net error pages and IIS Error pages?

Tags: asp.net, iis-7.5

there are two types of error pages in IIS

1. ASP.net .NET error
2. IIS Error pages

what is difference between ASP.net .NET error pages and Error page and IIS Error pages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.NET Error Pages are for displaying custom error pages when ASP.NET encounters an error (e.g. 404 for an .aspx page, or exception thrown while rendering an aspx page)

The Error Pages are for displaying custom error pages when IIS encounters an error (before it hands off processing a request to ASP.NET). These would be shown when a regular .html page encounters an error.

Answer from [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/466387/what-is-the-difference-between-net-error-pages-and-error-pages-in-iis7)